# How can I add a glow to my character in cycles?

Tags: glare

[image]

I want to add a golden glow to my character. A outline with a glow. Like the "outer glow" feature in Photoshop. It is a image to plane video with a color node and a alpha node. Ive seen alot of tutorials on how to do this in evee but not in cycles. I know they have a feature for this in compositing in the "glare" node. But that is for the whole image not just the character.

Comment: Can you post some reference image of desired result? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to do that ... basically you need generate outline to be used as a mask.

If you have already alpha channel you can use **Dilate/Erode** node at Alpha socket for such mask ...

[image]

... or use **Inpaint** node at Image socket.

[image]

There is a plenty of variety to work with ... if you will be more specific I can extend my answer.

[image]
[image]

---

Since your character is part of 3D scene you have to separate it ... in this example I used Render Layers.

[image]

For that ...

- All objects except character object keep in one *Collection* and character object in a new *Collection*.
- In *Outliner* editor create a new *View Layer* with this setup ...
  (I named it accordingly, but you can choose what ever you like.)

[image]

[image]

In compositor ...

[image]
[image]

... or it depends on your goal (that I asked for already).

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello. that looks good but that is in compositing. How can i isolate my character in compositing because right now if i add those effects its going to be for the whole image

Comment: it says my file is too big but the character is in the scene. It is a moving video file that was shot on the green screen. It uses two image textures. A color and a alpha to get the transparency.

Comment: heres a google drive link https://drive.google.com/file/d/10n-nCSp9Lzl2kN0ORvE5oNcx62h6pZwl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok thank you. ive been to get this to work for awhile

Comment: If solution works for you consider [mark answer as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), so others can see it is solved from a main list and system is not pocking up your question repeatedly. You can change your mind any time. Thank you keep this site organised.