# How to add outer glow in evee on a transparent object?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[video](https://imgur.com/a/r5ZMDO3)

I had my outer glow set up in the compositing for cycles, but it took way too long so I switched to evee. Im trying to create a golden outer glow for my character. I added another material and I tried to use the Material offset in the solidify modifier but since my object has transparency it creates the glow around the whole object not just my character. The object has a color image node and a alpha image node to make this character.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: If you're talking about the bloom effect, it can only be on the whole scene in Eevee, if you want to make a specific object glow, you need to use the Compositor, either in Eevee or Cycles

Comment: what would i use in the conposistor in eevee?

Comment: Is there anything that doesn't work for you in Eevee from my answer in your [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293352/2214)?

Answer (score 0):

*Solidify* modifier is extruding geometry not textures.
If you need to generate thickness based on alpha you can fake it by using *Volumetric* shader (...but I'm not sure Eevee can handle it, so Cycles way).

---

In general ... If you think you can manage this effect with just *Solidify* ... you can use this Shader setup ...

[image]
[image]

The key to isolate specific material to be get into account (and only this material) by Bloom here is **Bloom > Threshold**.

To isolate material for bloom set shader **Emission > Strength** to something higher than anything in your Scene. Like here I set *Strength* to 10 and under adjust *Render Properties > Bloom > Threshold* until just a your "rim" is glowing.